# Windows 7 Failed to boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

I tried to recover my windows 7 64bit after a System Repair Boot Loop but now it fails to boot with error:

```
File: \Windows\system32\winload.exe
status: 0xc000000f
Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt
```

I tried to add a new boot entry that's where it failed. 
Any help on how to fix my system?

Comment: Did you try replacing winload.exe with a known good copy?

Comment: can i do that using the windows 7 installation DVD?

Comment: Yes, but it will probably be inside Install.wim and need to be extracted with something like 7-Zip. Or easier still you can copy it from a friend's PC etc.